# Any extra steps required to upload file to external domain via HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I am developing a web application for a client where they need to post a file to and in turn I respond with some XML.

The client application uses the HttpRequest class to perform the request.

The request itself completes because they get back the XML, but if I count the number of files in Request.Files, it is always 0.

Now, I am capable of explaining to them how to simulate a file upload via this method, but I am not sure whether it is a problem that the request originates from an external domain.

The request originates from a Winforms App at a remote site.

Is this a problem, or does a 200 response from my site mean that they should be able to include a file in the request?

UPDATE: 
Or in other words: would the entire request be blocked, or is it possible that only the file gets stripped and the rest of the form data is allowed to reach the end point?

Comment: Have you had a look at the request coming across the wire? If it doesn't actually include the files, it's clearly a client fault.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out: whether the request being processed (sans file) means that it's not a cross-domain problem, but something further back on the client.

Or in other words: would the entire request be blocked, or is it possible that only the file gets stripped and the rest of the form data is allowed to reach the end point?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that just part of the request would be stripped, but you should be able to determine this yourself with Wireshark or something similar. The first step should be reproducing this on a client you control (e.g. connecting from your home, just to be in a different domain).